# How to set up API URL without question mark for the ID in WEB API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am trying to get all data and single data through the WEB Api. When I get single data I have to put "question mark" in the URL however I don't want it. How can I avoid doing this.

I want to completely remove the ?C_ID= part;
http://localhost:xxxx/api/Candidates/?C_ID=1

I want to have a URL like this to get single candidate
http://localhost:xxxx/api/Candidates/1

```
 namespace JobPortalX2_Server
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {

        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            //CORS
            config.EnableCors();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "GetCandidatesRoute",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
            );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "GetCandidateRoute",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}"
            );

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to use `method overloading` in your web api controller class.

Comment: Can you please up-vote this question?

Answer (score 3):

You already have it; second route will take care of it. Or you can just replace both routes with the following default one -

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional});
```

If you use Web API 2 and want to use **C_ID** as a parameter name, you can use **RouteAttribute**.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/candidates")]
public class CandidatesController : ApiController
{
   [HttpGet]
   [Route("{c_id:int}")]
   public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int c_id) 
   {
      ...
   }
}
```